# Можно ли начинать абзац с "при этом"?

Tags: грамматика, оформление-текста, абзац

По-моему, нельзя, *"при этом"* может продолжать предложение, или с него может максимум начинаться новое, но не абзац. Или это всё-таки возможно?

Answer (score 6):

> Можно ли начинать абзац с “при этом”?

Ну а почему бы и нет? Можно. **[См. пример:](https://books.google.ru/books?id=7Enu75hVefMC&pg=PA9&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%22%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF-Jz6is7OAhUDWCwKHWlXCRA4MhDoAQg4MAU#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%22%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86&f=false)**

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или **[другой пример](https://books.google.ru/books?id=6PjZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA427&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%22%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxzcSN0M7OAhUGKywKHcsXD_0Q6AEIOzAG#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%22%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false)** (Тихонов А. Н. и др. *"Энциклопедический словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов и понятий"*):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Частный случай. После маркированного перечисления с любым текстом по другому не выйдет. Может быть ещё примеры есть?

Comment: Да, вот если бы без перечисления был хороший пример...

Comment: Ну, к примеру, см. это: https://books.google.ru/books?id=96VkI0mckQkC&pg=PA162&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis6tmkm87OAhWHECwKHYKjBWY4HhDoAQgqMAM#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%22&f=false

Comment: Или это: https://books.google.ru/books?id=KT7QAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT153&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4g9PBms7OAhVK1ywKHYOYDGQ4FBDoAQg9MAc#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%22&f=false

Comment: В примере books.google.ru/… автор жжёт — три абзаца кряду. Маниак. Если по тексту пробежать, — встретятся и однако, и кроме того, и отсюда, и с другой стороны.

Comment: Ну, не знаю... Спасибо хоть за это!

Comment: Добавил к своему ответу пример из словаря-справочника, написанного известными лингвистами. Достаточно?